# What templating engine to use with node js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, templates, reactjs

I have node js BE. I only want to implement layouts - include header and footer on all pages. Templating engines such as pug (jade), ejs, etc seem like an overkill for this purpose.

What would you recommend?

Also might be relevant: I am most likely going to end up using either angular or react, are they a valid way to implement this (layouts)?

Answer (score 1):

`React` itself has a powerful template engine. Create a single layout page and include all your components into that layout. It'll be a single page app with the layout as the base and the content inside changes based on the user action.

Comment: So I would use react router? Or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: You can you react router or more simple page.js

Answer (score 0):

I use [mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/), it is easy to use with lots of options.
By the way, a template engine does not depend on if you use node.js or not, right.

Comment: Well, for example jade is compiled on BE and then sent as plain html, isn't it? Another reason I mentioned is that I thought there might exist some node specific solution. And thanks for the tip, I will have a look.

Comment: Actually i dont know. I use also node.js with mustache.js where node.js sends some data to the client and mustach renders everything. So the server don't prepare the plain html which leads to less server load.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Handlebars(.hbs). It also provides lot of options which are good and easy to use and configurable.

Here is the link:

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars
2. http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html